# IP to ASN mapping algorithm

Tags: bgp

Is there no easy way to map a given IP adress to the corresponding ASN number? For example:

ping to find out the IP adress:

```
$ ping www.switch.ch
PING aslan.switch.ch (130.59.108.36) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

whois lookup for the ASN number:

```
$ whois -h whois.cymru.com -v 130.59.108.36
Warning: RIPE flags used with a traditional server.
AS      | IP               | BGP Prefix          | CC | Registry | Allocated  | AS Name
559     | 130.59.108.36    | 130.59.0.0/16       | CH | ripencc  | 1993-09-22 | SWITCH SWITCH, Swiss Education and Research Network
```

So the mapping in this case would be `130.59.108.36` (IP)-> `559` (ASN). Easy. But what if I would like to create my own local mapping service with the public available information from the Regional Internet Registries? So, for the above example, it would be this list, right?

```
ftp://ftp.ripe.net/pub/stats/ripencc/delegated-ripencc-latest
```

And to find the matching entrie is also not a problem:

```
ripencc|CH|ipv4|130.59.0.0|65536|19930922|assigned
```

But how do I get the ASN number from the line above?? How are those two informations linked together?

```
ripencc|EU|asn|559|1|19930901|allocated
```

Thanks in advance for a reply!

Answer (score 11):

I explain how to do this here: https://www.quaxio.com/bgp/ (formerly at https://alokmenghrajani.github.io/bgp/)

It basically involves downloading a dump from a router and then using an efficient data representation to map an IP address to a netmask.

Comment: Hi. So, just to get my fundamentals correct, your method provides an alternative to obtaining the same information, as provided by Maxmind (see the answer above)? Or is it qualitatively any different? Thanks

Comment: Fundamentally, it's probably the same. It's less magic. I explain how to get the raw data. I explain how to process it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd propose doing this based on MRT dumps collected from an actual BGP speaker.

There is this python library f.e. that can be used to easily parse MRT dumps: http://code.google.com/p/pyasn/

If you're not able to run your own BGP speaker, you can download dumps at http://archive.routeviews.org/

Make sure you checkout their other stuff too. They provide also DNS zonefiles that would enable you to do such lookups using a standard DNS server such as Bind or NSD: http://archive.routeviews.org/dnszones/

I hope that gets you started...

Comment: very nice! does the archive.routeviews also contains the historical mappings between `ASN` and company names?

Answer (score 0):

I have made a tool that appends ASNs to HTTP log lines. I explain how to build the database off RIPE raw data and use it with binary search. Also, C code is ready for use. 1.6M look-ups in a few seconds on a regular virtual instance:

https://github.com/psvz/tirexASN